# Get articleID from ID of recently clicked link

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<a href="#" id="article-2341234" class="article-link">click to see article</a>
<div id="article-body-2341234" style="display:none;"> ...
...
...
</div>
```

Now I want to do this:

1. prevent default
2. get articleid '2341234' from the id of the link just clicked
3. hide the link and display the article below it

**I also want to capture the recently clicked link in a variable as I will refer to it many times in the click event and I want to be effecient.**

I have this so far:

```
$(".article-link").bind("click", function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var articleId = ?????;

$("#article-link-" + articleId).hide();
$("#article-body-" + articleId).show();


});
```

I need a generic function that will get the 'articleid' from the ID of the element, how can I do this?

How can I store the recently clicked link in a variable so I can refer to it again.  Is it:

`$(this)`  ?

Comment: You'll have to provide the name of the articleId so that we can figure out how to get it from the id of the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to simply do a `replace()` on `this.id` to grab your article id.

```
$(".article-link").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var articleId = this.id.replace("article-link-", "");
  $(this).hide();
  $("#article-body-" + articleId).show();
});
```

*Side note*, you can just do `$(this).hide()` instead of querying the dom again as `this` will refer to the dom element clicked.

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/PcaRX/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

**this** will refer to the currently clicked element, so you can use for instance a regex (this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]) to fetch the number

Comment: could I get the # after the last instance of the dash character?

Comment: That regex gets the number the id ends with, the number is at the end of the id, correct?